# how to do a circular shift the edge of sub matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

i want to rotate only the edge of sub matrix in python
but i don't know how

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24
25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
```

i want to make above matrix to below

[image]

how can i do it as simple as possible in python?

```py
src = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]
```

```py
det = [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12],
       [1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 18],
       [7, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]
```

Comment: My basic outline would be: 1. creating smaller matrix of the part you want to rotate. 2. perform the rotation. 3. replace existing matrix with new one.

Comment: I want to know the rule of rotate? why did you only rotate row 0,1,2?

Answer (score 0):

```
s=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
m=[]
def up():
    k=0
    l=[0]*len(s[0])
    for i in range(len(s[0])-1):
         l[i]=s[k][i+1]
    l[-1]=s[k+1][-1]

    m.append(l)
def down():
    k=len(s)-1
    l=[0]*len(s[0])
    for i in range(len(s[0])-1):
         l[i+1]=s[k][i]
    l[0]=s[k-1][0]
    m.append(l)

def mid():
     for j in range(1,len(s)-1):
          l=[0]*len(s[0])
          l[0]=s[j-1][0]
          for k in range(1,len(s[0])):
               l[k]=s[j][k]
          l[-1]=s[j+1][-1]
          m.append(l)

up()          
mid()  
down()
print(m)
```

Output:
`[[2,3,6],[1,5,9],[4,8,12],[7,10,11]]`
So here s is the matrix whose boundary you have to rotate anticlockwise by 1 element. m is the final matrix. The function up(), mid() and down() respectively append the first list, middle lists, and last list to m. You will have to slice the array accordingly to perform the operation.